# MacBook Air 13 2015 screen glitches

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, gpu

The screen shows inverted colors, noise in some parts. Can someone please tell me what to do?

[image: Screen Problem]

Answer (score 1):

## Go to a certified Apple Support Provider (Apple Store or similar)

The will be able to repair your computer.